# How to become a "Verified entity" on Stellar Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, nodes, verification, validators

A number of nodes appear as "verified entity" in the Featured live network nodes section on https://dashboard.stellar.org/. Who is verifying and what are the requirements to be listed as "verified"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We will be redesigning the Nodes section of the Dashboard really soon so it's very likely that the "verified node" will be gone.

The reason we added a "verified node" badge was that we wanted to list both:

- the companies we work with (like IBM)
- nodes run by developers from our community (we often don't know outside our Slack).

By adding a special badge to some nodes we wanted to emphasise that we know that these nodes are run by a real company (ex. IBM).

Comment: "We" ...

are you part of the Stellar foundation?

Comment: @RubberDucky yes.